# Combine ErrorListPlot with DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I made a few months ago the following list

```
data={{{1, -1.21}, ErrorBar[{-0.26, 0.279}]}, {{2, -1.22},
ErrorBar[{-0.267, 0.282}]}, {{3, -1.255},ErrorBar[{-0.263, 0.278}]}, {{4, -1.317},
ErrorBar[{-0.263, 0.278}]}, {{5, -1.2109},ErrorBar[{-0.2612, 0.275}]}}
```

and I want to have these points in ErrorListPLot howevere instead of x axis with 1,2,3,etc i want to have years from 2006 up to 2010 but i am not quite sure how to do it because of the ErroBar as the third element of the list. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you look at the package `ErrorBarPlots`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              data = {{{1, -1.21}, ErrorBar[{-0.26, 0.279}]}, {{2, -1.22}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.267, 0.282}]}, {{3, -1.255}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.263, 0.278}]}, {{4, -1.317}, 
   ErrorBar[{-0.263, 0.278}]}, {{5, -1.2109}, 
   ErrorBar[{-0.2612, 0.275}]}};
   d1 = First /@ data; d4 = Table[i, {i, 2006, 2010, 1}]
   d6 = Last /@ data; d5 = Last /@ d1
   d7 = Transpose[{d4, d5}]; d8 = Transpose[{d7, d6}]
   ErrorListPlot[d8, PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 0}}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image: plot of data]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is works great